# Can't insert checkbox data in sql database ( not stored or null in database ) - using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

As per question title i can't manage to insert checkbox data into database

Here is my model

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
      array(  'field' => '_butype_',
              'label' => 'Business Type',
              'rules' => 'required|trim|alpha_numeric_spaces|min_length[2]|max_length[50]'),

      array(  'field' => '_bumotiv_[]',
              'label' => 'Motivation',
              'rules' => 'required'),

    );
  
  }

  public function getById($id){
    return $this->db->get_where($this->table, array($this->primary => $id) )->row_array();
  }

  public function getAll() {
    return $this->db->get($this->table)->result_array();
  }

  public function insert(){
    $post = $this->input->post();
    if (!empty($post)){
      $data = array(
        'ginfo_id'           => NULL,
        'ginfo_butype'       => htmlspecialchars($post['_butype_']),
        'ginfo_bumotiv'      => json_encode($$post['_bumotiv_[]']),
      );

      $data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
      if($this->db->insert($this->table, $data)){
        $response = array(
          'status' => 'success',
          'message' => 'Success insert data',
        );
      } else {
        $response = array(
          'status' => 'error',
          'message' => 'Failed insert data',
        );
      }
    } else {
      $response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Data not found!',
      );
    }
    return $response;
  }
```

Here is my Controller

```
public function add(){
    

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->M_Ginfo->rules());
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('notif', $this->M_Ginfo->insert());
      redirect(site_url('admin/ginfo/add'),'refresh');

    } else {
      $data['notif'] = $this->M_Auth->notification();
      $this->load->view('admin/ginfo/add.php', $data);
    }
  }
```

Here is my model

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="_bumotives_[]" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" style="text-align: left;">What actually motivated you to start your own business? </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-group" type="checkbox" name="_bumotiv_[]" id="_bumotiv_[]" value="To be independent from working for other people" <?php echo set_checkbox('bumotiv_[]', 'To be independent from working for other people', false); ?>>
        <label for="_bumotiv_[]" >To be independent from working for other people. </label>
        <br>
        <input class="form-group" type="checkbox" name="_bumotiv_[]" id="_bumotiv_[]" value="I have a bright idea that can be commercialised" <?php echo set_checkbox('bumotiv_[]', 'I have a bright idea that can be commercialised', false); ?>>
        <label for="_bumotiv_[]" >I have a bright idea that can be commercialised.</label>
        <br>
</div>
```

There are other data that got insert successfully only checkbox is the only form field that has not been submitted to the database

I tried many solution but non worked for me
Any help is appreciated

Comment: If I remind you that Un-Checked checkboxes are not returned in `$request` would that help?

Answer (score 0):

- If non of the checkbox is selected you will not get any result for checkbox.
- Check your code for insert query there is an extra `$`

```
    'ginfo_bumotiv'      => json_encode($$post['_bumotiv_[]']),
```